# Enabling @KafkaListener to take in variable topic names from application.yml file

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

I am attempting to load in multiple topics to a single `@KafkaListener` but am running into trouble as I believe it is looking for a constant value, but initializing the `topics` variable from the `application.yml` file causing something issues, I was wondering if someone could help me troubleshoot this issue, or provide me with direction into how to load multiple Kafka topics into a single KafkaListener.

I am able to listen to multiple topics in the same `@KafkaListener` by passing them in a comma delimited object as seen below:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = {
           "flight-events",
           "flight-time-events",
           "service-events",
           "flight-delay-events"
   })
```

I realize I could do an object with comma delimited values representing the topics, but I want to be able to add topics through a config file, rather than changing code in the code base.

I believe there may be the problem in that @KafkaListener needs to take in a constant value, and I am unable to define an annotation as a constant, is there any way around this?

`KafkaWebSocketConnector.java`

```
@Component
public class KafkaWebSocketConnector
{


   @Value("${spring.kafka.topics}")
   private String[] topics;

   @KafkaListener(topics = topics)
   public void listen(ConsumerRecord<?, Map<String, String>> message)
   {
      log.info("Received messages on topic [{}]: [{}]", message.topic(), message.value());
      String dest = "/" + message.topic();
      log.info("destination = {}", dest);
      log.info("msg: {}", message);
      messageTemplate.convertAndSend(dest, message.value());
   }
}
```

`application.yml`

```
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      group-id: kafka-websocket-connector
    topics: flight-events,
      flight-time-events,
      canceled-events,
      pax-events,
      flight-delay-events
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Answer provided from @Gary Russell from this GitHub issue:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/361

You can use a SpEL expression; there's an example in EnableKafkaIntegrationTests...

```
@KafkaListener(id = "foo", topics = "#{'${topicOne:annotated1,foo}'.split(',')}")
```

In my case `"#{'${spring.kafka.topics}'.split(',')}"`

I was able to implement the above code, (provided by Gary Russell) in order to answer the above question.

Comment: That's called *plagiarism*... You have not to create GH issue for questions, please.

Comment: Sorry Artem, I know you're a tag team with Gary, is there a better citation that I can apply to this to resolve the issue you have with this answer?

Comment: You have to add the link to that GH issue for more info and accept your answer. In the future just keep in mind that we might not be available on-line to answer questions on GH. That's why SO is the best place to start with.

Comment: Thanks Artem, I understand and hopefully the changes that I made to the answer will alleviate your original issue. As for accepting the answer, SO doesn't allow me to accept my own answer to my own question for 48 hours, but I will be accepting the answer ASAP.

Comment: If you don't need multiple topics Listener the expression might be simpler: `@KafkaListener(id = "myListener", topics = "${topics.myTopicName}"`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @terrabl's answer. However there was a minor mistake. We need to use `.split(', ')` instead of `.split(',')`

Answer (score -1):

This solution work well :

```
@KafkaListener(
      topics = "#{propertiesClass.getListOfTopicToListen()}",
```

In the yaml file

```
topicsToListen:
        - topic-1
        - topic-2
        - topic-3
```